# How to find long and lat from map url and then making it more dynamic by passing the long and lat as param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, url

I am new to vue js and am stuck with embed google map url. I have google and searched a lot but not getting what I want.
I have this url for example:
*"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d20041.58914746939!2d17.008093249999998!3d51.10479505!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1644570663221!5m2!1spl!2spl";*
and from this url I am  trying to get the lat and long, so I can make them more dynamic and not just hardcode it. Any help will be much appreciated!

So far I tried this below, i want to pass long and lat as param or as variable (  + lat + long...) :

```
 computed: {
    src() {
      const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=";
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        center: `${20041.58914746939},${17.008093249999998}`,
        zoom: 15,
        size: "300x300",
        maptype: "terrain",
      });
      return `${url}?${params}`;
    },
  },
```

```
// also tried with this example ( nothing seems to work): 

 computed: {
    src() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=";
          const myLatlng = `${position.coords.latitude} , ${position.coords.longitude}`;
          const params = new URLSearchParams({
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 15,
            size: "600x300",
            maptype: "terrain",
          });
          console.log("params", params);
          console.log("mylatlong", myLatlng);
          return `${url}?${params}`;
        });
      }
    },
  },
```

and then using as props in Iframe:

```
<template>
  <iframe :src="src" class="map" />
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the URL format is always the same, maybe you can just use `RegExp` like this:

```js
const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d20041.58914746939!2d17.008093249999998!3d51.10479505!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1644570663221!5m2!1spl!2spl';

const matchLat = url.match(/!2d.*!3d/g)[0].match(/d.*!/g)[0];
const matchLon = url.match(/!3d.*!2m/g)[0].match(/d.*!/g)[0];
const lat = matchLat.substr(1, matchLat.length - 2);
const lon = matchLon.substr(1, matchLon.length - 2);

console.log('Lat: ', lat);
console.log('Lon: ', lon);
```

Comment: Thanks @Fernando, But I am trying to pass the long and lat as param, as the url can have different lat and long, something similar to this:  "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d20041.58914746939!2d "+${position.coords.latitude}+ !3d+ ${position.coords.longitude} + !2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1644570663221!5m2!1spl!2spl";

Comment: or similar to this: 
src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?center=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&zoom=13&size=800x400&sensor=false";